# How to retrieve items from large list using rest API?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-list

I have a list having approx 10000 items, I am trying to retrieve items filtering by '**UserEmail**' column, using REST api.

```
http://SpServer:1122/sites/Large-List-PORTAL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=ID,Title,Category,UserEmail,ProductName&$filter=UserEmail eq 'myemail@domain.com'&$top=5000
```

Even though the expected item count is less only hundreds, i am getting the following error.

[image: Error Image]

How do I overcome this?

Thanks in advance.
Divakar

Comment: UserEmail field needs to be indexed.

Comment: As bhasker mentioned UserEmail  columns need to be indexed. Increasing List view threshold at Web application may be not suggested by sharepoint admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you just have to increase the list vie threshold value.

Open Central Administration.
Go to Application Management > Manage Web Application and select your web application
In the Ribbon, click on General Settings drop-down and choose “Resource Throttling”.
In the “List View Threshold”, increase the value
Try to replicate the error: If it persists, increase the value again
Hope this helps !

[Reference here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/bb7cf9b5-1473-4ab8-be32-75a62a34dc10/the-attempted-operation-is-prohibited-because-it-exceeds-the-list-view-threshold-enforced?forum=sharepointadminprevious)